# How to organize functions.php content

Tags: php, theme-development

When building custom themes, I often add my own functions inside `functions.php`:

```
<?php
    function my_function() {
            // Do something...
    }
```

Should I organize all my custom functions inside hooks?

```
<?php
    add_action( 'init','my_init' );
    function my_init() {
            function my_function() {
                    // Do something...
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't nest functions like that, you should look up classes namespaces and object oriented code

Comment: If I group my functions inside a class, how can I use them later with functions like `add_action()` or `add_filter()`?

Comment: @Camilo replace `'function_name'` with `['class_name', 'function_name']`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation available about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tom J Nowell says, don't nest functions. Just write them normally:

```
function my_theme_prefix_setup() {
    // Add theme support etc.
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_prefix_setup' );

function my_theme_prefix_init() {
    // Register a post type
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_prefix_init' );
```

Or using a class:

```
class my_theme {
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'setup' ) );
        add_action( 'init',              array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }

    function setup() {

    }

    function init() {

    }
}

$my_theme = new my_theme;
```

Or using a "static" class (no instantiation) - since the class pattern in themes/plugins is often a glorified namespace, use them as such:

```
class my_theme {
    static function run() {
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( __class__, 'setup' ) );
        add_action( 'init',              array( __class__, 'init' ) );
    }

    static function setup() {

    }

    static function init() {

    }
}

my_theme::run();
```

[Then there's namespaces](http://torquemag.io/using-namespaces-wordpress-development/). So long as you're running PHP >= 5.3 (which you should be, though as @Nicholas mentions, you can't rely on for public themes - WordPress minimum requirements are only 5.2.4), this is the *real* solution that the above classes are attempting to resolve.

That said, there is no one *right* technique. Pick whichever suits the job, and that you're comfortable with. So long as you keep it clear, consistent and maintainable, you're doing it right.

Comment: If you're writing a theme or plugin for public consumption, you can't guarantee PHP 5.3+

Comment: Thanks, I ended up organizing everything into classes without namespaces.